# Pagination in home.ctp not clickable data

Tags: cakephp, pagination

home.ctp

```
<?php 
    echo $this->element('distromob/featured');
?>
```

WebsitesController.php

```
<?php
    class WebsitesController extends AppController {   
    public $components = array('Paginator'); 
    public function index(){
        $images = $this->paginate('Website');
        if (isset($this->params['requested'])) {
            return $images;
        } else {
            $this->set('images', $images);
        }
    }
```

featured.ctp

```
<?php 
 $images = $this->requestAction('/Websites/index');
?>
   <ul>
          <?php     
          foreach($images as $image): ?>
          <?php $domain =  $image['Website']['domain'];?>
             <li><?php echo $this->Html->image('websites/' . $image['Website']['image'],array('width'=>'234px','height' =>'208px','class' => 'random')); 
             ?>
             </li>
             <?php endforeach;?>
         </ul>
     <?php echo $this->Paginator->prev('« Previous', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?> 
        <?php $this->Paginator->counter(); ?>
        <?php echo $this->Paginator->next('Next »', null, null, array('class' => 'disabled')); ?>
```

AppController.php

```
class AppController extends Controller {
public function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Paginator->settings=array(
              'limit'=>4
       );

  }
}
```

Im new to cakephp I found some tutorial on the web but it seems not fit on my needs. My question was, why is it the previous and the next pagination data is not clickable, It seems that the pagination data is base on the limit i set on

```
public function beforeFilter(){
    $this->Paginator->settings=array(
              'limit'=>4
       );

  }
```

whenever i change the limit it will also display data but i cannot click the next and the previous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make the pagination data available in the element i.e $this->params['paging']

```
//index method
 if ($this->params['requested'])
    return array('images'=>$this->paginate('WebSite'), 'paging' => $this->params['paging']);

$this->set('images', $this->paginate('WebSite') );
```

then in your home.ctp do this

```
$images = $this->requestAction(array('controller'=>'websites','action'=>'index'));  

// if the 'paging' variable is populated, merge it with the already present paging variable in $this->params. This will make sure the PaginatorHelper works
if(!isset($this->params['paging'])) $this->params['paging'] = array();
$this->params['paging'] = Hash::merge( $this->params['paging'] , $images['paging'] );
```

Comment: I try your code sir, but it display "An Internal Error Has Occurred."  
I put this code in element since i just called a file in home.ctp
featured.ctp
$images = $this->requestAction(array('controller'=>'Websites','action'=>'index'));  
if(!isset($this->params['paging'])) $this->params['paging'] = array();
$this->params['paging'] = Hash::merge( $this->params['paging'] , $images['paging'] );

Comment: please set debug level to 2 to get in the core.php to get detailed error. it could be small typo. but you get the trick merging the paging params in home.ctp because the home.ctp wasn't the primary view and hence unaware of the requested action Model

Comment: the first code snippet sh'd go in the controller index method, then last code to home.ctp

Comment: Thanks dudz...  i can now click the link numbers but i wonder why when i click the pagination number it will say "The requested address '/www.url.com/pages/home/page:2' was not found on this server. "  how can i fixed this thank you

Comment: if you have route connected for current action i.e index, then just add this to your featured.ctp $this->Paginator->options(array('url'=>array('controller' => 'websites', 'action'=>'index')));

Comment: be default the Paginator sets current url as its target. in your case you are in diff controller so set the url option like above

Comment: I got it dudz.. but i want only the bottom section will be updated when i click pagination numbers in this case? it will go to another view. http://url.com/Websites/index/page:3 ,, is it duable to have this link . http://url.com/pages/home/page:2 , i want only the bottom section will be updated which has the images section.. it means im only on home.ctp. thanks for your help dudz..

Comment: yes is possible. cakephp supports ajax pagination. they are many example s online just google "cakephp ajax pagination"

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing ->counter() with ->numbers() to see if you have any page numbers

Comment: still no number display  only the « Previous and Next »  but not clickable , is there a code need to add ?

Comment: this is becoz the data on which paginatorHelper depends i.e $this->param['paging'] on is not sent to element on in the parent view . please see my answer below